# Can't connect to wireless

Tags: wireless

Ubuntu won't connect to my wireless. Windows connected just fine, in the same spot. When I try and connect, it tries for a minute or so, then says "disconnected, you are now offline" 
The signal strength is fine.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal ctrl+alt+t and paste this command in

"lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net"

this will let us see what wireless device you have so we will know if it will work when ubuntu is installed, but in my opinion it is not worth the trouble to try to get it to work from a livecd

Comment: Okay. Stupid question... Its on a different computer- how do i get the line in the middle there? Sorry, i'm not so great with computers

Comment: Vertical bar, i mean

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out, haha